# Error on standard record page after transferring Case

Tags: case, error, sharing, standardlayout, record-owner

We have 'Customer Support' users and for them, we have created a checkbox field called (Forward to Sales Team). Once they make this checkbox field true, we are changing the case owner to the 'Sales user' queue through the workflow. The case owner is getting changed but on the standard record page of 'Customer Support' users after making checkbox true and hitting the standard 'Save' button throwing the error, and the error is because the owner is changed and the current user will not have access of that case. We don't want to show this error message on this record page (It is confusing), instead we can show some custom message or we can refresh the current page URLs. I am not getting any idea how to overcome this issue.
Attaching the error screenshot below.

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue is? You want to make your own error message? You could just have a validation rule so you can make your own message display or do the same (addError) in the before update in the trigger.

Comment: One option will be to go custom. Create a new custom lightning component and there transfer the case.
Also make sure your user have 'Transfer Cases' permission.